# TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'function'

Tags: python

This is the function I have. I am using it to simulate a Hamiltonian:

```
#Create the Hamiltonian of the interaction
  
def Hamiltonian(t):
      
      
      #The transition frequency
      omega_trans=1
      
      #Create the sawtooth frequency chirp
      def theta(t):
          def eta(t):
              eta=signal.sawtooth( 2*np.pi *t)
          return eta
          theta=eta-omega_trans*t
          return theta
      
      #Assemble Hamiltonian
      Ham=(hbar/Omega)*(sigma_plus*np.exp(-theta*1j) + sigma_minus*np.exp(theta*1j))
      return Ham
```

And I get this error:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'function'
```

Why?

Comment: specifically, as the answer says: "the operand (of the unary (-)) is a (function), and that's not permitted".  Unary here = one operand, so you're looking for a `-` with only one thing next to it.  There's only one such `-`: the one in front of `theta`.  So `theta` is a function, and the unary - isn't able to do anything sensible to functions.  Of course, as the answer says, you meant to *call* theta to get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `(-theta*1j)`, while `theta` is a function. Perhaps you meant `(-theta()*1j)` to get the value returned from the function.

#### Edit:

There are some more issues, it seems. Using `theta(t)` will not solve the problem yet. That is because the `theta` function returns `eta`, which is a function. You can verify this by placing `print(type(theta))` and `print(type(theta(t)))` on the lines before `Ham=...`, and you can see that they both are a function. With other words, `theta` is a function that returns a `function`, while it should return a value.

I believe you need to indent `return eta` one layer deeper. Furthermore, I heavily recommend against naming your variables the same as your functions, or you will "override" your functions.

```py
# Create the Hamiltonian of the interaction
def Hamiltonian(t):

    # The transition frequency
    omega_trans = 1

    # Create the sawtooth frequency chirp
    def theta(t):
        def eta(t):
            # I've renamed eta to eta_val for the value
            eta_val = signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * t)
            return eta_val # I've indented this.

        # I've renamed theta to theta_val for the value
        theta_val = eta(t) - omega_trans * t # I've used eta(t) instead of eta
        return theta_val

    theta_val = theta(t)
    # Assemble Hamiltonian
    Ham = (hbar / Omega) * (sigma_plus * np.exp(-theta_val * 1j) + sigma_minus * np.exp(theta_val * 1j))
    return Ham
```

Some of the differences are marked by comments to help you decipher the changes made.

Comment: I have just used:                                                                                                         Ham=(hbar/Omega)*(sigma_plus*np.exp(-theta(t)*1j) + sigma_minus*np.exp(theta(t)*1j)).                                                                                                 and I get the same error

Comment: @LudovicoIannizzottoVenezze. Then show your new code where you really uses `theta(t)` and still gets the same error.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some more of the issues with your code.